# how to import video and audio libaries

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, multimedia

I want to make a Multimedia player for Android Platform  can someone guide me regarding the SDK I have to use for such task  other than the android development kit , or do I have import libraries , if yes where can I find them

Any tutioral or link will be welcome

Kind Regards
Kishor joshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Go for the this  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Read the documentation , discover a little about the Media Player class  that is what are its Fields , is it  a subclass and finally the Interface

Then here are some links :

www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zGS_zrL0rY‎

http://www.verious.com/board/58211/building-a-custom-android-audio-player/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irdwVCDcMug

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm

Comment: @KishorJoshi If  this answer helped , do not forget to give me like

Comment: Ok @Taimoor ali i will try it.But can you help me how to set a designed media player as default media player for all videos on my android phone

Comment: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/214935-change-default-music-player.html